# Query to read when column has 2 values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need some query help

| User | country |
| --- | --- |
| Non | US |
| Sam | US |
| Ram | IND |
| Ram | US |
| Tom | US |
| Tom | IND |

Please help me with the query to select the users which are assigned with both countries like the output below

| User | country |
| --- | --- |
| Ram | IND |
| Ram | US |
| Tom | US |
| Tom | IND |

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using analytic functions one approach might be:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, MIN(country) OVER (PARTITION BY User) AS min_country,
              MAX(country) OVER (PARTITION BY User) AS max_country
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT User, country
FROM cte
WHERE min_country <> max_country;
```

This assumes that `country` would always have a value and that value would always be one of either `US` or `IND`.

Answer (score 1):

This query might be helful:-

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TableName a
JOIN (SELECT user, country, COUNT( * )
      FROM TableName 
      GROUP BY user
      HAVING count(*) > 1 ) b
ON a.user = b.user
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Find out users who are having more than one occurence (Assumption is there are no duplicate rows)
2. Apply Group by and Having Clause to achieve result set of step 1
3. Apply a Join with the source table again using User Column and retrieve all the matching rows from the source table

Query

Select A.* from UserDetails A Inner Join
(
Select [User] from UserDetails group by [User] having count(*) > 1
) B
On A.[User] = B.[User]